# Magento2: Bundle Product add to cart without selecting options (Product Item)

Tags: magento2, addtocart, bundled-product

I am working on cms page custom product layout for that I have written custom controller. but it show error

> {"0":"Please select all required options.","1":"#1
> Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\Interceptor->addProduct() called at
> [app/code/Vendor/SmallBusiness/Controller/Index/AddCart.php:73]\n#2
> Vendor\SmallBusiness\Controller\Index\AddCart->execute()
> called at
> [generated/code/Vendor/SmallBusiness/Controller/Index/AddCart/Interceptor.php:24]\n#3

Below is my controller

```
namespace Vendor\SmallBusiness\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;

class AddCart extends Action 
{
    protected $formKey;   
    protected $cart;
    protected $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        FormKey $formKey,
        Cart $cart,
        ProductRepository $productRepository) {
            $this->formKey = $formKey;
            $this->cart = $cart;
            $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;      
            parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
     { 
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id');
        $quote = $this->cart;
        $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById($id);

        $selectionCollection = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)
                           ->getSelectionsCollection(
        $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($_product),$_product);

         // create bundle option
        $cont = 0;
        $selectionArray = [];
        $selectionqtyArray = [];
        $selectionpriceArray = [];

        foreach($selectionCollection as $proselection){ 
            $selectionArray[$cont] = $proselection->getSelectionId();
            $selectionqtyArray[$cont] = $proselection->getSelectionQty();
            $selectionpriceArray[$cont] = $proselection->getPrice();
            $cont++;
        }


        // get options ids
        $optionsCollection = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsCollection($_product);
   
        foreach ($optionsCollection as $options) {
           $id_option = $options->getId();
        }    
        
        // generate bundle_option array
        $bundle_option = [$id_option => $selectionArray];
        $bundle_qty = [$id_option => $selectionqtyArray];
        $bundle_price = [$id_option => $selectionpriceArray];
        
        $params = [
                    'product' => $_product->getId(),
                    'bundle_option' => $bundle_option,
                    'bundle_option_qty' => $bundle_qty,
                    'bundle_option_price' => $bundle_price,                           
                    'qty' => 1,
                    'original_qty' => 1
                  ]; 


        $quote->addProduct($_product, $params);
        $quote->save();
        
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for this

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json as ResultJson;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;

class Addtocart extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var ProductFactory
     */
    private $productFactory;
    /**
     * @var Cart
     */
    private $cart;
    /**
     * @var FormKey
     */
    private $formKey;
    /**
     * @var JsonFactory
     */
    private $resultJsonFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param FormKey $formKey
     * @param JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     * @param Cart $cart
     * @param ProductFactory $productFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        FormKey $formKey,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        Cart $cart,
        ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return ResultJson
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $resultData = [
            'status' => 'success',
            'status_code' => 1,
            'message' => __('Products Added successfully.')
        ];

        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $qty = 1;

        $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);
        $productsArray = $this->getBundleOptions($product);
        $params = [
            'product' => $productId,
            'bundle_option' => $productsArray,
            'qty' => $qty
        ];

        try {
            /**
             * Add bundle product in cart
             */
            if ($product->getId()) {
                $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
                $this->cart->save();
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $resultData = [
                'status' => 'fail',
                'status_code' => 0,
                'message' => __('Unable to add the Product. Exception ' . $e->getMessage())
            ];
            return $result->setData($resultData);
        }
        return $result->setData($resultData);
    }

    /**
     * get all the selection products used in bundle product
     * @param $product
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function getBundleOptions(Product $product)
    {
        $selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance()
            ->getSelectionsCollection(
                $product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsIds($product),
                $product
            );
        $bundleOptions = [];
        foreach ($selectionCollection as $selection) {
            $bundleOptions[$selection->getOptionId()][] = $selection->getSelectionId();
        }
        return $bundleOptions;
    }
}
```